# Html color renders as a different color from what is set in CSS - Cross browser issue on Mac (all browsers have this problem)

Tags: html, css, colors

I have a strange issue I cant get my head around. I'm working on a macbook pro, and this issue only seems to exist on mac. (on pc, iphone and android the same page looks and also reads fine when checking the color code in photoshop)

The problem:
I've set an html background-color to #070707 and all browsers render it as #080808. example: https://adambernath.com/vidi.html
If I take a screenshot of the page and check it in photoshop it shows as #080808 when the code is #070707, the bigger problem is that it also shows as the background is visibly lighter color compared to the video (again, only on mac)

This is obviously an problem when trying to match a color to a videos background color (which is actually #070707) - trying to adjust it to match it also wont work as then on every other type of device it will be darker than the video

The macbook's color profile is set to Apple RGB (although it should not influence how a color is rendered in the browser as it may or may not show different from other displays, but the color code should not change)

Any ideas?

Comment: I tried this on a macbook pro and I can't reproduce what you describe, I guess if you inspect the css in the browser the color code will be the correct one

Comment: if you pick color from the left side of the image, do you see 070707 or 080808?
https://pasteboard.co/Jzlduge.png